# Sitecore PowerShell session issue: a script needs to be executed in the session

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am running a script and I am using loop concept to get certain data.
But a session timeout error was encountered during the script execution and the script stopped running.

Issue: `A script needs to be executed in the session before the variable value can be inspected.`

I am new to using `PowerShell` script and have no idea how to resolve this kind of error.

Here, I have attached a demo script and error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in Advance.
Manish

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of error?

Comment: I have attached screenshot in description with session tooltip error.  Script randomly stopped running after 25000.

Comment: and what is your Sitecore version?

Comment: It's a Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 180406)

Answer (score 0):

This issue typically happens when the session object cached on the server in memory is lost. Most often this happens after the script completes or the application pool in IIS recycles.

You may want to design your script to support restarting from the last completed step. For example you could update an item or write progress to a database table.